# Shared preferences not working as intended

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preferences to store an int that will be the highscore of a game I've created. The problem is that it doesn't get stored at all. When I restart my device/shutdown the app or whatever the highscore is gone. What's the problem?

Store

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", highScore);
editor.commit();
```

Retrieve

```
SharedPreferences sp1 = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int highScoreSaved = sp1.getInt("your_int_key", 0);
```

let me know if you want me to add any more code. Thanks!

Comment: Are you retrieving the data in the same class where you store the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this when getting `SharedPreference` instance:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this /* Current context */);
```

So key-value pairs will be store in the default file that all the activities in the application will share, whatever context you pass to it.

However if you do not want to use a default instance of the file, you can just edit you code to make it use application context:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Usually I prefer the first approach since is more flexible and easy to use with a single-instance file.

Comment: Yes this works. I used your second option as I find that a little simpler to understand. Thanks, this was really annoying me!